# C++: Converting Array class to Class template (Scope issue)

Tags: c++, arrays, templates, scope

I'm in the early stage of trying to convert an array class containing operator overloading into a templatized class. At the moment I'm trying to add the template definition to the class and each function. This should be fairly simple however, whenever I run the program I get a scope error.

The compiler says `T' was not declared in this scope (I will comment the error on the line that it occurs). The error also re-occurs on the other function definitions. I'm using a program invovling a templatized class as a guide and it implements the functions in the exact manner that I am trying to(which is why I'm confused). What do I need to do to resolve this?

Thank you.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <iomanip>
#include <cstdlib>
#include <stdexcept>
using namespace std;

#ifndef ARRAY_H
#define ARRAY_H

template <typename T>
class Array
{
  public:
         Array(int = 10);
         Array(const Array&);
         ~Array();
         int getSize() const;

         const Array &operator=(const Array &);
         bool operator==(const Array&) const;

         bool operator!=(const Array &right) const
         {
              return ! (*this == right);     
         }     

         int &operator[](int);
         int operator[](int) const;
  private:
          int size;
          int *ptr;        
};

#endif

template<typename t>
Array<T>::Array(int arraySize) //ERROR: T was not declared in this scope***********
{
 if(arraySize > 0)
              size = arraySize;
 else
     throw invalid_argument("Array size myst be greater than 0");

 ptr = new int[size];

 for(int i = 0; i < size; i++)
              ptr[i] = 0;   
}

template<typename t>
Array<T>::Array(const Array &arrayToCopy): size(arrayToCopy.size)
{
 ptr = new int[size];

 for(int i = 0; i < size; i++)
         ptr[i] = arrayToCopy.ptr[i];                  
}

template<typename t>
Array<T>::~Array()
{
 delete [] ptr;              
}

template<typename t>
int Array<T>::getSize() const
{
 return size;   
}

template<typename t>
const Array<T> &Array::operator=(const Array &right)
{
 if (&right != this)
 {
    if(size != right.size)
    {
            delete [] ptr;
            size = right.size;  
            ptr = new int[size];
    }

 for(int i = 0; i < size; i++)
         ptr[i] = right.ptr[i]; 
 }  

 return *this;
}

template<typename t>
bool Array<T>::operator==(const Array &right) const
{
 if(size != right.size)
         return false;

 for(int i = 0; i < size; i++)
         if(ptr[i] != right.ptr[i])
                   return false;

 return true;     
}

template<typename t>
int &Array<T>::operator[](int subscript)
{
 if(subscript < 0 || subscript >= size)
              throw out_of_range("Subscript out of range");

 return ptr[subscript];   
}

template<typename t>
int Array<T>::operator[](int subscript) const
{   
    if(subscript < 0 || subscript >= size)
                 throw out_of_range("Subscript out of range");

    return ptr[subscript];
}

int main()
{
    //main is empty at the moment because I want to make sure that the class is functional
    //before implementing the driver function.

    system("pause");  
}
```

Comment: Never do "using namespace ..." in a header. This is considered extremely bad form.

Comment: It's not really a header. I'm just using one .cpp file at the moment, until I seperate it.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Before each of your function definitions, you have written:

```
template<typename t>
```

You mean:

```
template<typename T>
```

That is, it should match the template parameter of your class, which is a capital `T`.

Comment: Also most of the ints should be replaced by T.

Comment: @drescherjm I think he hasn't gotten to that part yet.

Comment: Wow. Thank you, sometimes you just need someone else to look at your code, right? @drescherjm: that's my next step, to switch everything to template parameters that need to be one.